# Want to set two column in mysql in one table as auto increment int

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set two columns in MySql as `auto increment (int)`

S.NO Q_id

I want to set both auto increased.

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not possible to have two auto increment columns inside one table. Period. You can get the same effect using a stored procedure or a trigger, but usually such a requirement is a hint that your data model is not well crafted.

Answer (score 0):

In same table you can't use two auto increments fields. You can create a integer field and add value +=1 in php

```
...
$row_last_id++;
INSERT INTO ... values(id, $row_last_id)
```

Comment: It stop data entering other question please can i have demo plss

Answer (score 0):

Updated Try this: It can be possible with use of  MyISAM storage engine try Below Code

CREATE TABLE `invoices` ( `S_NO` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `Q_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL, `date` date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (S_NO,Q_id) ) COMMENT='' ENGINE='MyISAM'

Comment: In your example just one field auto_increment? what about second field?

Comment: one field will be primary key with auto_increment and other field will be only auto_increment